# Search SQL table column data using LIKE operator

Tags: c#, sql-server

The SQL table has 20835 rows. This table needs to be searched (returning a column only) in a foreach loop in a C# code. This Foreach loop is executed for some 35,000 times.

So, I made an Index in the table (made of two columns) for fast searching returning the Index column itself. Using this Index with the help of `SqlDataReader` in the C# codes...

But, its too slow.. Takes about forever to complete this action.

So, made a Dictionary. Here, we do a `TryGetValue()` for seaching a key value...

So its like searching a dictionary where `KEY='value'`.

[`TryGetValue()` is a fast search...]

But what if we need to do where KEY starts with/contains search???

Is there any way??

One way is:

```
var values = dictionary.Where(pv => 
             pv.Key.StartsWith("A").Select(pv => pv.Value);
```

But, its a slow search process...

Any other way?? I need to do a search and that searching must be fast...

Comment: What kind of data within these ~21.000 rows is to be searched? Please give example of data and search strings. Do you search for string "StartsWith" or do you have to search for contained words? Do you search for contained words complete or - worst case - for any short string on any place within a longer string? Is there need for place holders too?

Comment: This sounds like A-B question. Can you please talk us through what data you need to search and what search terms there will be. Possibly this can be done with pure SQL and not doing any C# search.

Comment: The 4 columns are-
 [SourceIngredientName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
 [IngredientInfoSource] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
 [PIingredientName] [varchar](250) NULL,
 [LastActvtyTime] [datetime] NULL..
Like operator to be applied on `PIingredientName` column and returning `SourceIngredientName`. Index is made using both these 2 columns.
I would like a StartsWith search..

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use [Full-Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)?

Comment: @Martheen I am unable to create Full search Indexes.. I am using Sql server Management studio 2014. I get zero(0) for SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'). And not able to add any feature to existing installation of SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment you want to perform a "StartsWith" search on PIngredientName.

For this you need an index on this column and a query like

```
SELECT SourceIngredientName WHERE PIngredientName LIKE @SearchString + '%';
```

~21.000 rows are not so much and a `LIKE 'Pattern%'` query on an indexed column is really well performing. This should be lightning fast...

I'd pack the query into a inlineable TVF like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SearchIngredient(@StartWith VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT SourceIngredientName, OtherColumns WHERE PIngredientName LIKE @StartWith + '%';
GO
```

And than call it like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchIngredient('test');
```